# How can I get into iPad's system files using Ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, ipad

I recently found out how to restore iDevices using terminal with "idevicerestore" it worked however I still couldn't accomplish my aim. I am trying to delete a device management profile and I think I can do it from iPad's system files. Does anyone know a way to access those?

Comment: MDM is not a system file -- it should be present in the backup, but be aware that [MDM profiles can be pushed remotely](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/MobileDeviceManagementProtocolRef/3-MDM_Protocol/MDM_Protocol.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access anything Apple doesn't want you to unless you jailbreak. Otherwise, you're limited to a sandbox that lets you see photos, music, some documents and that's it.

Not even Android lets you access system files without rooting. iOS most certainly won't. If you are jailbroken, then this question is better suited for http://apple.stackexchange.com.

KazWolfe has pointed out that you may be able to access what you want from a backup. However, this is definitely something that you will need to ask for on Ask Different.